# Binding data to grid view is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net

In the below code i have get 2 variable in a session and i am tried to bind values in custom control by passing client id and in another case i tried to bind another values to grid view by passing doumnet id .But custom controls are binded successfully but grid view cant able to bind it throws error.pls help me to solve the issue

pageload:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                var SearchDoc = (SearchDoc)Session["Documentname"];
                var oDocumentID = SearchDoc.ClientID;
                var odoc = SearchDoc.DocumentID;
                DocumentServiceClient Doc = new DocumentServiceClient();
                DataSet dsField = Doc.GetClientFields(oDocumentID);
                DataSet dsField1 = Doc.GetDocumentsByDocumentID(odoc);//
                gmaFieldsContr.dtFieldsInfo = dsField.Tables[0];
                gmaFieldsContr.BindData();
                Attchdwnld.DataSource = dsField1.Tables[0];
                Attchdwnld.DataBind();}}
```

Comment: please always provide sufficent data in question so other can easily understand and help to solve the query.please give what error you are facing.

Comment: @Sunil Devre @ serhads the issue has been solved

Answer (score 0):

I solve the issue

```
 var SearchDoc = (SearchDoc)Session["Documentname"];
                var oDocumentID = SearchDoc.ClientID;
               string odoc = SearchDoc.DocumentID.ToString();
                DocumentServiceClient Doc = new DocumentServiceClient();
                DataSet dsField = Doc.GetClientFields(oDocumentID);
                DataTable dtDocument = Doc.GetDocumentsByDocumentID(odoc).Tables[0];
                gmaFieldsContr.dtFieldsInfo = dsField.Tables[0];
                gmaFieldsContr.BindData();
                Attchdwnld.DataSource = dtDocument; 
                Attchdwnld.DataBind();
```

Comment: DataTable dtDocument = Doc.GetDocumentsByDocumentID(odoc).Tables[0];...your not selecting table[0] hence facing error is it right?

Comment: I change var to string now the values are binding